# Hashing & Salting - Validating login w/ cookies

Tags: php, authentication, cookies, hash, salt

So this is basically a reassurance that I'm doing the whole registration/login process right as far as hashing/salting goes.

I have a users table with the fields password, salt, token (obviously there are others but this is the most important). Upon registration it generate a random salt, and a random token, and it puts in the password field this:

```
hash("sha256", $theirpostpassword.$randomgeneratedsalt);
```

That random generated salt and token are stored in their respective fields in that users row in the table.

So upon login I select the salt ONLY from the users row with the username they specified. I then do a count query of how many rows have their post password concatenated with their specific salt, and then I log them in. Pretty sure I have that part down.

Now I was thinking to validate their login on every page I would have a function ran every page that checks their cookie to see if the format of id-username-token matches the row in the database. Meaning that every login it sets their cookie with those credentials.

Now the only thing I can think of to make it better is change the token every valid login?

Thanks for the insight guys.

Comment: I would have the token depend on the IP of the remote user, but checking that cookie -with that info- on every request seems to work just fine.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I was kind of against IP checking entirely since I know there are some dynamic IP addresses that change quite often.

Comment: You should not create authentication system yourself because so many things can go wrong. Use facebook connect/twitter sign in/openid etc instead!

Comment: @Alfred: Though these are very popular authentication methods, who is to say that you want them controlling your user details and hoping they don't suffer from a large data breach. Dan's project probably has the advantage of being a much smaller, and therefore less likely, target for hackers.

Comment: If they(universal login) get breached you only have to modify 1 password. If everybody has another login system you have to chance all the passwords(because most people use the same passwords for all websites)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you should definitely be changing tokens with every login. Otherwise a token stolen once is an account stolen forever. Users expect that logging off secures their session from attack by invalidating their cookies or other data.

Rather than the token being random, you can make it serve as a signature, by generating it from a hash of the user id, session expiry time, and whatever else you want in the cookie, plus a salt (just like the login system). This salt doesn't have to come from the database, but it can. It could be a hardcoded string (sometimes called a "pepper" I think). Remember to treat the cookie as invalid if it's past the expiry time. That's why the token should be a signature, to make sure they didn't spoof that data.

Comment: I disagree with the token being a signature. You need the token to be unguessable and the only way to guarantee that is with randomness. By all means have a signature as well, but a random token is very important.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds pretty good to me, but you should be aware of a couple of things:

To make your password database resistant to brute-force attacks you could iterate the hash:

```
$hash = $password;
for ($i = 0; $i < 1000; ++$i) {
    $hash = hash("sha256", $hash . $salt);
}
```

Second, make sure you use SSL all the time. Without it, it's pretty trivial for an attacker to steal the login cookie. See firesheep for a good example of how trivial it is.

Definitely change the token every login and consider changing it for every request to prevent session fixation and replay attacks.

You could also select the salt and the hash from the database and do the hash comparison server-side (rather than on the DB) to reduce the number of round-trips to the database.

I'd suggest that the token be entirely random. You want it to be unguessable and the best way to do that is random. You **could** tie the token to a particular IP address as well but this should be in addition to a random token, not a replacement.

That's all that springs to mind. Good on you for asking for advice rather than just MD5-ing the password and sticking it in the database!

Answer (score 1):

> checks their cookie to see if the format of id-username-token matches the row in the database

You could but this is rather expensive and you're not addressing the problem of session management - setting a cookie expiry time in the past does not always cause cookies to be deleted. By all means consider this for a remember me type of function (but use an offset path to avoid presenting the cookie every time).

You're not gaining anything over storing the authenticated user name in the session. But do change the session id when you authenticate a user and do use SSL for passing authentication tokens.